# Cannot read file data from jsp file on remote server

Tags: java, jsp, openshift

My dynamic web project has following structure.

WebContent/WEB-INF/jsps/index.jsp. I'm trying to access file.txt from my jsp file and display content from that file. file.txt is in WebContent/resources folder.

I'm using,

`String jspPath = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources");
jspPath = jspPath.replace("\\", "/");
String fileName = "/file.txt";
String txtFilePath = jspPath + fileName;`

After opening file, code to display content.

It is working on localhost but when I upload it online, it is not displaying content from text file on jsp page.

I'm not getting why it is not working, I think filepath might be a problem because it was throwing FileNotFoundException but I fixed it by making few changes. Now it is not displaying content. Can someone please help? I'm uisng openshift deployment platform for .war file.

Comment: It's not a good idea using file paths to read files deployed in a server. Different machines use differents file systems and some applications servers compress the deployed content. Why don't you use better getClass().getResource("/resources/file.txt") ?

Comment: I already tried but it is giving this error : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP.

Comment: It seems that your code is  wrong or you forgot some import. If you are reading the file as stream check that you include <%@page import="java.io.*"%> Anyway, are you sure that you wanna put this logic into a jsp? Write java code in a jsp is obsolete, there are easy ways to make things.

Answer (score 1):

Actually , your above JSP page will never be executed because it is in the `WEB-INF` folder which is not accessible for the end users, so make sure to put your JSP's out of WEB-INF.
For reading the file , you can load and print the file in simpler way:

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<% 
InputStream in=config.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/hello.txt");
int ch;
while((ch=in.read())!=-1){
    out.print((char)ch);
}
in.close();
%>
```

Since the above method of calling `getRealPath` will not work with application servers using virtual file-systems like JBoss.

Note: for better performance , you can use other methods of reading files to include(e.g. Buffering and caching), but this will be out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I'm using spring and displaying jsp page using controller and view resolver. All the jsp files are in WEB-INF/jsps folder and they are working fine on my machine. Also, all the other jsp files are working fine on openshift server but the one jsp file, which is opening text file, is not reading content from the text file and displaying it. All the static content of that jsp page is being displayed but the data from the text file is not being displayed.